# how to prevent an onchange inside a form from running when clicking submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that submits data along with images that are uploaded with an onchange ajax function inside the form. They are added with hidden tags when the upload runs, but the problem is that the last image upload is running again when the form is submitted, probably because of the onchange function being inside the form.

Is there any way to prevent the onchange from running again when somebody clicks the submit button? The structure is like this:

```
<form id="upload_form" action="new.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ad_create_form">

<input class="upload_button" type="file" name="item_file_upload_1" id="item_file_upload_1"
   onchange="media_sync(ad_create_form, 1, 
   this.form.item_file_upload_1, 
   document.getElementById('item_file_url_1').value, 
   document.getElementById('item_file_embed_1').value, 
   document.getElementById('nb_uploads_1').value, 
   5, 
   '000000015');"  />

<input name="finish" id="finish" value="Add" type="submit" class="btn">

</form>
```

So I'd need the onchange to run as many times as somebody clicks on the upload button, but not anymore when somebody clicks on the submit button. Is that possible?

Comment: i dont see the jquery here? You want resolve the problem in vanilla js or jquery?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to over-complicate it :) The jquery function is actually the `media_sync` but I want a way to somehow prevent the `onchange="media_sync..."` from running again when the submit button is clicked :)

Comment: gibberish has good answer. My idea for jquery is create onchange event and detach him if you sending the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a brainstorming idea than a decent answer, but hopefully it will give you ideas that lead to a solution.

Simplistic idea: create a var that tells you if the submit button has been pressed, and look for it in the onchange function.

For example:

```
var no_run = false;

function media_sync(data){
    if (!no_run){
        //ajax code goes here - files uploaded
    }
}

$('form').submit(function(){
    no_run = true;
});
```

Note that you must define the `no_run` var outside any functions.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle to play with**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dmjL5j9/)</kbd>

Comment: That makes sense and I'm trying to get it working. So far without success but I'll keep trying, thanks a lot! :)